# CSS changing an object while hovering another

Tags: css, hover

I'm learning and experimenting with CSS right now. I have div with menu buttons and I want to change other buttons text when hovering one of them. Here is HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <h3 id="test">About me</h3>
  <h3 id="test2">Education</h3>
  <h3>Projects</h3>
  <h3>Photos</h3>
  <h3>Contact</h3>
</div>
```

In found out that I can do so in CSS:

```
#test:hover+#test2 {
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

Then, while hovering #test, the transparency of #test2 changes. That's so cool. But how can I change #test2 text, sth like:

```
 #text2=<h3>Different text</h3>
```

Greets.

EDIT:
That's good.
But why isn't this working?I only get #test2 changed to 'Get' when hovering...

```
<div id="menu">
  <h3 id="test">About me</h3>
  <h3 id="test2"></h3>
  <h3 id="test3"></h3>
  <h3 id="test4"></h3>
  <h3 id="test5"></h3>
</div>

#test2:before{
  content:'Education';
}
#test3:before{
  content:'Projects';
}
#test4:before{
  content:'Photos';
}
#test5:before{
  content:'Contact';
}
#test:hover+#test2:before {
  content:'Get';
}
#test:hover+#test3:before {
  content:'to';
}
#test:hover+#test4:before {
  content:'know';
}
#test:hover+#test5:before {
  content:'me';
```

Comment: you can easily do this using javascript or jquery .have u tried this?

Comment: I'm during my JS course, such thing has not been covered yet. 
You are right Jonathan, my idea was to have such menu that when I hover one element, I can then access others for links (kind of expandable menu). I should have thought about this issue, nothing to do without JS for me in this aspect. But thanks!

Comment: The `+` combinator requires the two elements to be *side by side*, which is why `#test:hover + #test5` won't work. You appear to be wanting `~` instead. See my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QwFgp/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change content with CSS...

CSS is just for the styling..

You could simulate something like this with the `:after` and `:before` (*pseudo-element contents*) but that means that the content would not really be accessible (*end the original content would also need to be defined in the CSS*)..

```
<div id="menu">
  <h3 id="test">About me</h3>
  <h3 id="test2"></h3>
  <h3>Projects</h3>
  <h3>Photos</h3>
  <h3>Contact</h3>
</div>
```

and

```
#test2:before{
    content:'Education';
}
#test:hover + #test2:before {
    opacity:0.8;
    content:'No Education';
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/65rxA/

---

Alternatively you could provide both contents in different tags and show/hide the one you want..

```
<div id="menu">
     <h3 id="test">About me</h3>
     <h3 id="test2">
         <span class="original">Education</span>
         <span class="alternate">Alternate</span>
     </h3>
     <h3>Projects</h3>
     <h3>Photos</h3>
     <h3>Contact</h3>
</div>
```

and

```
#test:hover + #test2 {
    opacity:0.8;
}
#test:hover + #test2 > .original, .alternate {
    display:none;
}
#test:hover + #test2 > .alternate {
    display:inline;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/65rxA/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo elements:

```css
.bar::after {
    content: "Old Text";
}

.foo:hover + .bar::after {
    content: "New Text";
}
```

Not a good approach though if you are concerned with accessibility. You appear to be wanting to target an element that is a general sibling, rather than contiguous with the hovered element. If that is the case, you should instead use the `~` combinator:

```css
#test:hover ~ #test2::before { content: "Get";  }
#test:hover ~ #test3::before { content: "To";   }
#test:hover ~ #test4::before { content: "Know"; }
#test:hover ~ #test5::before { content: "Me";   }
```

You can see the effect this has here: http://jsfiddle.net/QwFgp/

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#test").hover(function(){
      $("#test2").html("different text");     
   });
   $("#test").mouseout(function(){
     $("#test2").html("Education");     
   });
});
```

demo: [click here to see](http://jsfiddle.net/sharif084/aWyyk/1/) !